# In gcc How do I pad a numeric string with leading 0's?

Tags: c, printf, padding

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char UPC[]="123456789ABC";

main()
{
  int rc=0;

  printf("%016s\n",UPC);

  exit(rc);
}
```

On AIX using the xlC compiler this code prints out with leading 0's

```
0000123456789ABC
```

On Sles 11 it prints leading spaces using gcc version 4.3.2 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 141291]

```
123456789ABC
```

Is there some format specifier I could use for strings to print out with leading 0's?
I know that it works for numeric types.

Comment: Given the accepted answer… Do you not care about the trailing "ABC" in this example?

Comment: The accepted answer would print out the ABC as it interprets the number as hex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is undefined, implementation specific (glibc, rather than gcc). It's bad practice to rely on it, IMO.

If you know  for certain that your string is numeric (hexadecimal here), you could write:

```
 printf("%016llX\n",strtoll(UPC,NULL,16));
```

But be aware of errors and overflows.

**Edit by original poster:**

For decimal numbers use the following:

```
printf("%016llu\n",strtoll(UPC2,NULL,10));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("%.*d%s", (int)(w-strlen(s)), 0, s);
```

Comment: Hey, cleverer than mine.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

As far as `printf` is concerned, the effect of the 0 flag on the `s` conversion specifier is undefined. Are you restricted to `printf`?

[edit]
Here's an alternative, if you'd like (most error checks missing..):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char    UPC[] = "1234567890ABCDEF",
        out[sizeof UPC + 12]; /* substitute size for whatever you wish here, just make sure the original string plus NUL fits */
    if(sizeof out <= sizeof UPC) {
        return -1; /* you bad, bad man */
    }

    memset(out, '0', sizeof out);
    memcpy(out + sizeof out - sizeof UPC - 1, UPC, sizeof UPC);

    printf("%s\n", out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code in queston uses printf and sprintf.  I guess I could write my own version of printf and sprintf that handles it the way I want to but I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: Two other answers were posted. Try one.

Answer (score 2):

`%0*s` isn't standard.  You can do your own padding though:

```
char buf[16];
memset(buf, '0', sizeof(buf));
printf("%.*s%s", sizeof(buf) - strlen(UPC), buf, UPC);
```

Comment: @objblass: Oops, missed a character.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the printf man page, the 0 flag has undefined behavior for string arguments.  You'd need to write your own code to pad out the right number of '0' characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char spbuf[30];
 sprintf(spbuf, "%%.%ds%%s\n", 16 - strlen(UPC));
 printf(spbuf,"0000000000000000",UPC); /* 16 '0' characters */
```

Comment: Don't construct format strings programmatically in place of using `%.*d`. Your approach works, but it involves passing a non-literal format string which raises a (hopefully false) alarm for format string vulns.

Comment: I don't write format string vulns ever so I would have turned that warning off. Yes I have written stack overflows, heap overflows, array overflows, but never a format string vuln. I was very surprised when I learned this was a commonly exploited bug.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

Your code, when compiled, will result in : "warning: '0' flag used with ‘%s’"

The man page for printf lists the format specifiers that may be used after a '0' flag and they are all numeric.

You could, however, create a string with the appropriate number of spaces and print that ahead of your UPC.